# CommitStream webhook URL for Gitorious

Tags: versionone, gitorious

Are the webhook URLs generated by V1 CommitStream specific to a VCS? (They look the same on the CommitStream web page.) Will any of them, perhaps the GitLab URL, work with Gitorious? If not, does CommitStream have a generic webhook URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all webhook URLs provided are of a specific VCS family.

We have not tested any of them with Gitorious but I doubt they will work as the structure is likely different.

CommitStream does not have a generic webhook family.

Finally, because GitLab acquired Gitorious it's possible that they will use the same webhook structure in the future.